# Could the devices with different subnets communicate with each other in the same switching hub?

Tags: networking, routing

I'm learning about networking and how devices with different IP could communicate with router.

But I've some questions about communication. Could the devices communicate without the router? For example, if there are only 2 Linux system devices:

- A with IP `10.10.33.33/24`
- B with IP `10.99.20.20` in the same switching hub.

Could these two devices communicate? I thought that they could communicate with each other if they know other's MAC address with ARP.

I'm not sure that I thought correctly. Am I right?

Comment: Better not to use the term "switching hub".. Better to say either "switch" or "hub". By "Switching hub", the term "switch" is meant. As in, network switch.

Comment: You could only do this with a switch that has layer 3 (routing) capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

No. This won't work unless you add a secondary IP address on the other subnet on one of the interfaces because the boxes won't know how to send traffic to each other.

You are correct about arp.

Traffic which does not use the tcp/IP protocol will probably work.

Comment: You might be able to get them to communicate directly by adding a static arp entry for the opposite device. This would not be something a network administrator would typically do. You may be able to achieve solutions by having larger then required netmask so IPs overlap as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways tomake it work but with tcp/ip it would require static Routing rules on a device that both networks can access. I. e., your router if it is your default gateway or On an L3 switch like DrZoo said if you want them to talk nefore hitting your router.   If you’re new to networking,start looking into VLANs.  Learning how they work will make understanding how regular  LANS work as well.